# POO (French: Object-Oriented Programming) and def

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I need to get a variable insider another function, using OOP paradigmon in Python 3.

Maybe the example I wrote below can express better and more easily what I need to do:

```
class Mother:

    def first_def(self):
        var = 'Need this!'

    def second_def(self):
        var = 'Need  this!' # Need to pull from first_def to use here.
```

Well basically I need pull the `var` from `first_def` to use on the `second_def`.
Any clue on how I can do that?

Comment: What did you try?  Please post your code.  We are here to help you in programming PROBLEMS, not to write the code for you.

Comment: `return var` will do the job - but it will be better for you, to learn some basics. Take a book / tutorial and spend some time on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `var` an instance attribute. (I have no idea what you mean by "POO".)

```
class Mother:
    def first_def(self):
        self.var = "Need this"

    def second_def(self):
        # Do what you want with self.var
        print(self.var)


m = Mother()  # m.var not yet set
m.first_def()  # sets m.var
m.second_def()  # outputs "Need this"
```

Comment: I guess by POO, OP meant OOP

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that it can be done:

```py
class Mother:

    def first_def(self):
        var = 'Need this!'
        return var;

    def second_def(self):
        var = self.first_def()
```

Or you can set this variable as class variable and later access it:

```py
class Mother:
    def first_def(self):
        self.var = "Need this"

    def second_def(self):
        # Do what you want with self.var
        print(self.var)


m = Mother()  # m.var not yet set
m.first_def()  # sets m.var
m.second_def()  # outputs "Need this"
```